# Forçar Icone adaptativo a ser quadrado(Square)

Tags: android, icons

O melhor formato de ícone para meu aplicativo é o quadrado arredondado, no entanto, na api 26 e 27 sabemos que o android usa um ícone adaptativo predefinido (sempre em formato circular) ou transforma um ícone não-adaptativo (círculo com espaço em branco e ícone real pequeno).

Depois de muitos testes e buscas na internet, eu estava convencido de que deveria produzir um ícone circular, mas por sorte notei que o ícone do facebook nessas apis mantém seu padrão (quadrado arredondado de tamanho normal).

Como posso implementar isso na minha inscrição?

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua aplicação declara em `targetSdkVersion` a API26 ou superior não pode fazer nada.

A forma como o icon é apresentado depende da máscara aplicada pela aplicação *"Launcher*". Ela pode ser diferente de dispositivo para dispositivo e não *"sempre em formato circular"* como você disse.

Um icon adaptativo é formado por duas camadas, uma representa o background(fundo) a outra foreground(conteúdo).
A aplicação *"Launcher*" aplica uma máscara(quadrada, redonda ou outra) sobre essas camadas determinando assim o aspecto final do *icon*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Fonte da imagem: Android Guide - [Adaptive Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html)</sub>